# NVIDIA Driver version on NVIDIA X Server Settings

Tags: nvidia

hi I've manage to change my nvidia driver to prioprietary 340.46 from 331.89, however, when i check on nvidia x server settings it's 340.46 but when checking on software & updates on additional drivers tab it's on 331.89 radio button but the new driver(340.46) i upgraded to and downloaded from nvidia.com is listed but not on that radio button, weird?

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia v340.46, (which I am also using), has not yet been added to the Ubuntu repository. You must have installed it from the Nvidia website. There are no updates yet, and the Ubuntu update manager recognizes it as a manually installed driver.